# display two radiobuttons in a single line

Tags: html, css, radio-button

```
 <ul>
    <li  style="list-style:none;">
     <input type="radio" name="custom_type" value="public" />
      Public
     <input type="radio" name="custom_type" 
     value="private" id="custom_venuetype_private" />Private
     </li>
 </ul>
```

I have 2 radiobuttons.My issue is that both radio buttons are coming in two lines and there is some white spaces automatically coming after radio button, that is after the first radio button,some white space comes,then comes text.And the next radio button comes in the new line.I need both of then in single line and there should be no spaces required between text and radio button

Comment: added style="white-space:nowrap;"Then also the problem is still there

Comment: i copied your source as is, and to me it works oo both radios are in a horizontal line

Comment: maybe it got styled by some other CSS declaration you've missed. I'd `inspect element` using Chrome/Firefox to see what CSS are actually applied to the radios.

Comment: @rlatief I have inspected it,but i didnt find any problem

Comment: No unexpected CSS applied to the radios? How about the parents? The `li`, `ul`, etc... And you know how to look for the `calculated styles` in Inspect Element right? (just making sure).

Answer (score 3):

In order to place elements in one line, you can use **CSS** `display` property with `inline` value:

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <li  style="list-style:none;">
    <input type="radio" name="custom_type" value="public" />
    Public
    <input type="radio" name="custom_type" 
    value="private" id="custom_venuetype_private" />
    Private
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.li {display:inline}
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQTEL/).

Comment: That should make `list` inline, not the radio buttons which by default is already `display:inline;`.

Comment: it is based on your need.you can choose li or input or ... .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is more hmtl and/or ccs around. I just tried it pure :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>

<body>
<ul>
    <li  style="list-style:none;">
     <input type="radio" name="custom_type" value="public" />
      Public
     <input type="radio" name="custom_type" 
     value="private" id="custom_venuetype_private" />Private
     </li>
</ul>

</body
</html>
```

and the output is in one line.

May be you have too small div around your ul or there is a definition for ul in your css.